# Lightbox 2 text color

Tags: lightbox2

I use Lightbox2 on my website. Everything is working well, but the description of the picture is not black and very badly readable. anyone knowing a solution?

regards

Markus

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change text style for description (color, font size, ...) editing lightbox.css in section
.lb-data .lb-caption {}